# Keyboard shortcut to place the cursor at the end of the modified filename

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

In Ubuntu GUI, to change the name of a file we can press F2. Then the name of the file will highlight, excluding the file extension. What is the keyboard shortcut to place the cursor at the end of the filename, that is after the last character of the filename (and before the extension)?

Comment: it seems to me like you aren't going to save many strokes with a shortcut compared to just pressing the right arrow key then the left arrow key a couple of times to get to the front of the extension...

Comment: Actually, this is exactly what I was looking for. Silly question. Please add it as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After clicking the filename and pressing <kbd>F2</kbd>

press the right arrow key <kbd>-></kbd>

and then press the left arrow key <kbd><-</kbd> a couple of times until you get to the front of the extension.

Not a shortcut, but still quite short ;)

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>F2</kbd> to edit the filename.

Press <kbd>End</kbd> to move the cursor at the end of the name.

Press <kbd>Home</kbd> to move the cursor at the beginning of the name.

Just like you do in a text editor. Does work for me in Xubuntu 16.04 and Thunar and PCManFM. It's kinda universal. It works in Windows too.